# Did Malik really sell the roof of his house in order to study?

Tags: reference-request, islamic-scholar

Until a few days ago I've heard to similar or identical statements about two different, but related scholars one saying:

> Imam Malik sold the roof of his house in order to study.

Another saying:

> Rabi'a ar-Ra'y (one of imam Malik's most famous teachers) sold the roof of his house ...

Now lately I found that both statements were mentioned in [Qadi 'Iyad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qadi_Ayyad)'s book Tarteeb al-Madarik ([ترتيب المدارك وتقريب المسالك لمعرفة أعلام مذهب مالك](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31215/128) -see the the quote below) the first, as a statement narrated by ['Abdurrahman ibn al-Qasim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Qasim) one of imam Malik's most famous Egyptian students and one could say the author or co-author of al-Mudawanna al-Kubar one of the most Maliki sources:

> أفضى بمالك طلب العلم إلى أن نقض سقف بيته فباع خشبه، ثم مالت عليه الدنيا بعد.
> It led Malik to seek knowledge until the roof of his house was demolished and he sold his wood, then the world turned away from him afterwards.
> وروي مثل هذا عن ربيعة.
> Such was narrated from Rabia.

My question is, is there anybody else confirming this claim?